# How made a deep copy that can resolve a problem with a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, deep-copy

Im using the table material-table, where the set a new element to my object, called tableData. So that feature create an issues to my code and API because I update using Patch. I implemented a conventional and also custom deep copy of my object to avoid the table add this element to my object.

But for some reason it isnt working. This is an example of the table where you can see how it added the tableData to the example object. https://codesandbox.io/s/lx2v9pn91m Please check the console

Above I showed the real object, and in the element 5 array, appear the tableData after each render. Extra comment, the property of the table I passed to table is: data={MyRealObject.element5}

```
This is the struct of my real object: 
MyRealObject{ 
element1: boolean, 
element2: boolean ,
element3: Array ,
element4: Array ,
Cards: Array ,
}

Card{ 
Id: number ,
CardNumber : number ,
CardFormat : {CardFormatObject},

//here where appear the tableData after each render 
} 

CardFormatObject{ 
Id: number ,
CardNumberLength : number ,
CardFormatLength : number ,
Default:boolean ,
Name: string ,
}

This is the lastest custom deep copy I did and didnt work:

deepcopy(MyRealObject:MyRealObject):MyRealObject{

let salvaCard=[]
for(let i=0;i<user.Cards.length;i++){
   salvaCard[i]=this.deepCardCopy(MyRealObject.Cards[i])
}
return{
      element1: MyRealObject.element1,
      element2: MyRealObject.element2, 
      element3: [...MyRealObject.element3], //I know here is not deep but isnt important now, and it isnt affected
      element4: [...MyRealObject.element4],

      Cards: salvaCard,


}as MyRealObject
}

public deepCardCopy(card:Card):Card{
    return {
      Id:card.Id,
      CardNumber:card.CardNumber,
      CardFormat:{...card.CardFormat}
    } as Card;
  }


//////////////////////////////

This are others deep code that I used and dont works, I share to save you time:
--------old solution 1(i dont like it, you can lose element if there are null)------------------------------------------------


// Cards: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MyRealObject.Cards)),

---------old solution 2-------------------------------------------

      // MyRealObject.Cards.map(card=>{
      //   const {tableData,...record}=card
      //   return record
      // }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solutions, it is passsing the clone in the moment i passed the object to the table, for example:

data={MyRealObject.map(x => Object.assign({}, x))}

The issues was, that the people that create the table didnt make a clone to the data, the use the same reference, so it will be better do this to avoid problems that some one in the component didnt clone the object.

Kindly, noted, DONT used this way 
data={...MyRealObject} or data={Object.assign({}, MyRealObject)}

The CORRECT is:
data={MyRealObject.map(x => Object.assign({}, x))}

Both expression look similiar but it isnot the same.

Comment: My deep Copy are OK, so you can use it without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is an **async** function. That means you won't see the result right after calling it. You have to wait for `setState` to be finished. There is a `callback`-Parameter in `setState` which you can use to get the result of `this.state`

```
handleSelectedID = rowData => {
    const selectedID = rowData.map(item => item.id);
    this.setState({ selectedID }, () => {
      // setState is async
      // this is the callback
      console.log(this.state.selectedID);
    });
};
```

I changed your example-code a bit to give you an example of it: https://codesandbox.io/s/1olz33pmlj

Comment: Hi, Manuel, thanks for your reply, but Im not asking that, my issues is tableData that appear in the object, it setted by the table. 

So I want to avoid that using a deep copy